# ExtendedExecutionSession in Windows 10 Universal app

Tags: windows-10-universal

I have task that is already running when the app is suspending. I need to request ExtendedExecutionSession to let the task finish executing.

I after obtaining deferral request ExtendedExecutionSession in app OnSuspending handler and the extended execution is granted.

When do I need to call deferral.Complete()? I found that if call in the end of OnSuspending after requesting extendedexcdution that execution does not work, the app stays in tombstoned state.

```
        private static async void OnSuspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
```

// request extended execution to let already running task to finish 
                await RequestExtendedSession();

```
// if  call this the app is tombstoned and no code is executing when the app is suspended
           deferral.Complete();

        }
```

Comment: The [ExtendedExecution sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution/cs/Scenario2_SavingDataReason.xaml.cs) says that you complete the deferral after you finish your extended execution.

Comment: Where do you see this? I could not find this comment in the sample. If I compete the deferral does it mean I should save in in a class member var?

Comment: Look at line 83, which completes the deferral. This is done after the long operation has completed (lines 63 to 68).

Comment: I understand this. By this sample assumes that inside OnSuspending you obtain the deferral, then extended session and then start executing code. I a;ready have code executing when OnSuspending is called. So the only way I can complete the deferral when my code finishes executing is to save the deferral in a class member var and call its Complete() method after the code is done executing.

Comment: Or you can have the OnSuspending handler wait for the already-active task to complete. The point is that when you complete the Suspending deferral, suspension proceeds. How you delay that completion is up to you.